# Diameter queries for stream of points

Tags: reference-request, ds.data-structures, cg.comp-geom

Given an online stream of $k$ points $x_1, x_2,\ldots,x_k$ with $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^2$. By *online* we mean that when $x_i$ arrives we have no knowledge of points $x_j$ for $j > i$. Denote by $S_i$ be the set of points $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_i\}$.

The goal is to answer *diameter queries*. That is, for any value of $i \leq k$ we can ask *"What is the diameter of $S_i$?"*. We can assume that we have access to $S_i$ and the diameter of $S_{i-1}$ when answering such a query.

The diameter of $S_i$ is defined as the maximum Euclidean distance between any pair of points in $S_i$.

I am seeking references for any papers discussing this problem. I can only assume it has been studied before however, I am unable to find any references.

Edit: As noted by @ChandraChekuri we could, of course, compute the diameter of $S_i$ for every $i$, but I hoped there would be something faster?

I guess the question rather is: Given a set $S_{i-1}$ and a point $x_i$ how quickly can we compute the diameter of $S_i := S_{i-1} \cup \{x_i\}$ assuming we have access to $S_i$ and the diameter of $S_{i-1}$?

Comment: Without any further constraints it is unclear why your problem is interesting. Why not computer and store the diameter of $S_i$ for every $i$?

Comment: @ChandraChekuri Fair enough. I hoped there would be something faster than computing the diameter $S_i$ for every $i$ . I updated the questions.

Comment: Dynamic algorithms are well-studied. You can look at this paper and references there in. https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/997817.997843?casa_token=0RKQ1n-XDVUAAAAA:gC2hvfm4o94WS1wW7EqRlDKLzXOj-VMmhK3GtUojpFltaYR9wrrQ4YGNEOY4zvikyDezCB_QzJM

Comment: Perhaps you might start by studying [dynamic algorithms for the convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_convex_hull).